# Multiples MessageBoxes - WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, messagebox

I have a game with 15 levels and when we finish a level it shows a MessageBox with the player's situation, before app navigates to a page with the next level objective.

However, that messageBox don't appears only one time, it's is displayed the number of times we play. For example, if we play the first level appears one time, but if we play the second level or if we repeat the first level the messageBox is displayed two times.

Why it happens? And how I resolve it?

This is my code:

```
void model_finishGame(bool playerWin)
{
    timer.Stop();

    if(playerWin==true)
       if(MessageBox.Show("Sucess!!! You Win")==MessageBoxResult.OK)
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LevelObjective.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    else
       if(MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you lose")==MessageBoxResult.OK)
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the reason is that you probably register for an event at the start of a level (maybe the timer event?) and never unregistering it so each time you start the level the event handler is called as many time as it has been registered (and I'm guessing the message box is shown from this event handler)

Comment: no it's just Stoping the timer not unregistering the event if you are reusing the same timer Timer object. To unregister it you need to do timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick; (where Timer_Tick is the function you are using ).

Comment: Thanks #Benoit Catherinet. I tried  as you said and didn't work. However today I look to the code by the other way and I found the problem: the event model_finishGame must be unregistered too. So with this two events unregisteds code works great. Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Counter** as the Integer and set it to **0** in the class.

And now,when the user completed the current Round displays the message which you want.
and increment the counter.

And now, every time check before displaying the message box whether the user completed the round and the counter is equals to 0 not Greater than 0 as like,

`if(counter==0)` then you will proceed as same with your code.